# Need to create a orphan process in perl

Tags: ruby, perl, fork, orphan-process

HI I am trying to execute a code by forking a child process.

I have ruby code a.rb in which i use system call

system("perl abc.pl -subroutine='a' -command='b' -status='c' -logfile='d' -start_datetime='e'")

now in abc.pl  i am doing this

```
my $pid = fork;
if (!$pid) {
    print "[INFO] in the child process \n ";    
    print "[INFO] forking worked, child process id: ($$) \n";
    while (1) { 
    if ( -d "$ENV{OUT_HOME}" ) {
        print "[INFO] $ENV{OUT_HOME} is available now to write $seq \n";
        open(my $FH,'>',"$ENV{OUT_HOME}/SEQ") or die "cannot open file to write $seq into $ENV{OUT_HOME}/SEQ";
        print $FH "$seq";
        close $FH; 
        print "[INFO] exiting from forked child process id: ($$)  \n";
        exit; # exit the while loop
    } 
    else {
        sleep (2);  
    }
  }
} else {
    print "[INFO] I am parent Process exiting from here \n";
    exit;
}
```

Now with this i am trying to get child process which is not dependent on parent process (here it is abc.pl) When i run the script, it does the system command which is running perl script and i see the perl script in process tree. But i keeps hanging there. I am not sure on why system command doesn't terminate after parent is done? any suggestions or comments appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of both the ruby and the perl, and let us know what you expect and what you observe instead.  For example, when I do `ruby -e 'system(*ARGV); puts "bye rb:#{$$}"' perl -E 'sleep 3 unless fork; say "bye pl:$$"'` ... it works!  I see the child perl exit, the parent ruby exit, and later its "orphaned" grandchild perl exit.  Whatever problem you have, I don't have it.

Comment: Re "*But i keeps hanging there. I am not sure on why system command doesn't terminate after parent is done?*", That is unlikely. Best guess: The child's STDIN, STDOUT or STDERR is a pipe, and whichever process is on the other end of the pipe is waiting for it to be closed. That is what's hanging, not `system`.

Comment: When daemonizing, you want to do a number of things, including: double fork, close all handles, and create a new session. [Daemon::Daemonize](https://metacpan.org/pod/Daemon::Daemonize) can be used to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new POSIX session for your newly-independent forked process.

Try this (assuming that the environment variable OUT_HOME has been set to a folder before calling perl):

```
my $pid = fork;
if (!$pid) {
    print "[INFO] in the child process \n ";    
    print "[INFO] forking worked, child process id: ($$) \n";
    require POSIX;
    POSIX::setsid();
    while (1) { 
    if ( -d "$ENV{OUT_HOME}" ) {
        print "[INFO] $ENV{OUT_HOME} is available now to write $seq \n";
        open(my $FH,'>',"$ENV{OUT_HOME}/SEQ") or die "cannot open file to write $seq into $ENV{OUT_HOME}/SEQ";
        print $FH "$seq";
        close $FH; 
        print "[INFO] exiting from forked child process id: ($$)  \n";
        exit; # exit the while loop
    } 
    else {
        sleep (2);  
    }
  }
} else {
    print "[INFO] I am parent Process exiting from here \n";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is addressed in [perlfaq8](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-fork-a-daemon-process%3F):

> **How do I fork a daemon process?**
>
> If by daemon process you mean one that's detached (disassociated from its tty), then the following process is reported to work on most Unixish systems. Non-Unix users should check their Your_OS::Process module for other solutions.
>
> Open /dev/tty and use the TIOCNOTTY ioctl on it. See tty(1) for details. Or better yet, you can just use the `POSIX::setsid()` function, so you don't have to worry about process groups.
>
> Change directory to /
>
> Reopen STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR so they're not connected to the old tty.
>
> Background yourself like this:
>
> ```
> fork && exit;
> ```
>
> The [Proc::Daemon](https://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Proc::Daemon) module, available from CPAN, provides a function to perform these actions for you.

As the FAQ states, the [Proc::Daemon](https://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Proc::Daemon) module can simplify this for you, although this is just one of several modules available for this task.